# Amazon Feed Error 25 for Order Fulfillment Feed

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, xsd, amazon-mws

For some reason, I have not been able to get this to work. I always get a response from Amazon saying `we are unable to process the xml feed because one or more items are invalid`. I have referenced the [schema](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/OrderFulfillment.xsd)  as well as the xml from [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977696/amazon-mws-order-acknowledgement-returning-error-25-we-are-unable-to-process-th), [other](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3953838&tstart=0), [posts](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2428153).

Example XML below with potentially sensitive info replaced

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>AXXXXXXXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OrderFulfillment>
<AmazonOrderID>111-2222222-3333333</AmazonOrderID>
<MerchantFulfillmentID>1</MerchantFulfillmentID>
<FulfillmentDate>2017-09-24T09:00:00-05:00</FulfillmentDate>
<FulfillmentData>
<ShipperTrackingNumber>1111111111111111111111</ShipperTrackingNumber>
</FulfillmentData>
<Item>
<AmazonOrderItemCode>22222222222222</AmazonOrderItemCode>
</Item>
</OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I was going off a template that said the CarrierCode or CarrierName was optional. Turns out it is not, you need to include one (and only one) of these tags.